# free type cast in generic linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

why does function list_destroy, free **current->data** twice if its a string, (since freeing twice leads to an error), but this doesnt. list->freeFn calls a function that is a free type casted to char*, but then free(current->data) is called again without a type cast, so does this one not work ?

why do we have to type cast free for strings (char*) but not int, would of assumed to do it to all types?

original tutorial: https://pseudomuto.com/2013/05/implementing-a-generic-linked-list-in-c/

```
void list_destroy(list* list)
{
    listNode* current;
    while (list->head != NULL) {
        current = list->head;
        list->head = current->next;

        if (list->freeFn) {
            list->freeFn(current->data);
        }

        free(current->data);
        free(current);
    }
}

void free_string(void* data)
{
    free(*(char**)data);
}


void list_new(list* list, int elementSize, freeFunction freeFn)
{
    assert(elementSize > 0);
    list->logicalLength = 0;
    list->elementSize = elementSize;
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    list->freeFn = freeFn;
}

void main()
{
    ...
    list list;
    list_new(&list, sizeof(char*), free_string);
    ...
    list_destroy(&list);
}
```

Comment: You're not showing everything but presumably `current->data` and `current` are pointing to different `malloc`ed memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic list implementation stores element values of a fixed size provided to `list_new()` along with a pointer to an optional callback function to free the element value when a list node is destroyed. The element size is stored in the list's `elementSize` member, and the callback function pointer (which is `NULL` if no callback function should be called) is stored in the `freeFn` member.

`list_append()` and `list_prepend()` add a new node to the list, and is provided with a pointer to the element value to be added to the list. They allocate a new list node and allocate a memory block pointed to by `node->data` to hold the element value, which is copied into the allocated memory block using `memcpy()`.

`list_destroy()` frees all nodes on the list, calling the `freeFn` callback function (if provided) with the `data` pointer for each element value. It is up to the callback function to define what it needs to do with the element value to free it. The callback function does not free the memory pointed to by the `data` pointer. It uses the value pointed to by the `data` pointer. It is `list_destroy()` that frees the `node->data` memory block that was allocated by `list_append()` or `list_prepend()`.

---

In the integer example, the value to be stored is just a value of type `int`. The list's `elementSize` member is `sizeof(int)`. The `freeFn` callback function pointer is `NULL` because nothing needs to be done to free an `int` - it is just a number. The example calls `list_append()` with a pointer to the `int` value to be stored. `list_append()` allocates a block of size `sizeof(int)`, pointed to by `node->data`, and copies the `int` value into it.

---

In the string example, the value to be stored is a `char *` that points to a dynamically allocated string buffer allocated by `strdup()`. That buffer needs to freed when the list node is destroyed. Therefore, the string example provides a pointer to the `free_string` function to free the string buffer that was allocated by `strdup()`. The example calls `list_append()` with a pointer to the `char *` value to be stored. `list_append()` allocates a block of size `sizeof(char *)`, pointed to by `node->data`, and copies the `char *` value into it. (Note: it is copying the `char *` pointer value itself, not the string contents. The string contents were copied by `strdup()`.)

The `free_string()` callback function receives a generic `void *data` pointer to a copy of the value that was pointed to in the call to `list_append()`. It points to a `char *` value, so the first thing it needs to do is convert the generic `void *` pointer to a `char **` pointer. It does that with a type cast operator: `(char **)data`. Then it *dereferences* the `char **` to get a `char *` value: `*(char **)data`. This `char *` value points to the memory that was allocated by `strdup()` and that needs to be freed: `free(*(char **)data);`.

If it makes it easier to see what `free_string()` is doing, it could have defined some local variables to hold the intermediate pointer values, like this:

```
void free_string(void *data)
{
    char **p = data;  /* convert pointer type (same as: char **p = (char **)data;) */
    char *strbuf = *p; /* dereference the pointer (same as char *strbuf = p[0];) */
    free(strbuf); /* free the buffer pointed to by the dereferenced pointer */
}
```

As you can see, `free_string` does not free the buffer pointed to by the `data` pointer. It just frees the buffer pointed to by the `char *` value that the `data` pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may see it if you do your own in-lining.  Take the line from free_string and put it in the list_destroy.  What you have is you do a free on data twice, but the data has already been freed.  Once option is to change the free_string to the following (casting is not required):

```
void free_string(void **data)
{
    free(*data);
    *data = 0;
}
```

and call it with `list->freeFn(&current->data);`

Comment: I think this would make the list implementation less generic. A `void *` can point to an object of any type, but a `void **` can only point to a `void *`.

Comment: Does it matter?  `free` is declared as `free(void *);`, so we have a void * anyway.

Comment: The point is that the `freeFn` callback should be able to be used to clean up any value. For example, if the list was used to store `struct foo` values with the type defined as `struct foo { char *a; char *b; }` with the `a` and `b` members pointing to dynamically allocated strings, the `freeFn` callback would be something like: `void free_foo(void *data) {` `struct foo *p = data;` `free(p->a); free(p->b);` `}`. See what I mean by "generic"?

Comment: I don't think it is worth a -1, but it is what it is.

Answer (score -1):

The result of `freeFn(current->data)` is `free(*(char **)data)` which is different from `free(current->data)`; although is dubious.  Note that the difference comes from dereferencing the data (&current->data) argument.

The tutorial is wrong, since the member data is not allocated.  A possible fix would be to change:

```
    if(list->freeFn) {
      list->freeFn(current->data);
    } 
    free(current->data);
```

to:

```
if(list->freeFn) {
  list->freeFn(current->data);
}
if (current->data) { 
   free(current->data);
}
```

and change:

```
void free_string(void* data)
{
    free(*(char**)data);
}
```

to:

```
void free_string(void* data)
{
    free(*(char**)data);
    *(char **)data = 0;
}
```

Comment: You are wrong - when a list node is created, space *is* allocated for the data.